# Problem with bone animation with 3D cursor as pivot

Tags: animation, armature, bones, keyframes, 3d-cursor

EDIT: I solved it by simply making smaller rotation increments with more keyframes. Would still be interesting to know the cause and if there's a better solution though.

So I'm trying to simply animate the rotation of a bone using the 3D cursor as a pivot. When I rotate it myself it works fine this way:

[image]

However when I animate it, the rotation ends up looking like this instead:

[image]

What's the cause of this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way animation work when you add a keyframe you store the variables values (loc, Rot, Scale) at that time, and when you play the animation blender try to interpolate ( guess ) the values of the variable (between keyframes ) depending on the last and next value and the type of interpolation used (this can be seen in the F-curve )

[image]

**so whatever happens between keyframes is lost and new value will be calculated**

---

in this case of the bone

- the location of the bone is the location of its head
- the bone will rotate around its head

in this example i keyframed the first and last states only :
[image]

***the result motion :***

the bone will follow straight path from the first pose to the last (blender can't  regenerate the original motion from those two states only) while rotating around its head

[image]

To prevent this you can :

- add more intermediate keyframes.
- or use an empty as a parent at the center of rotation.
- or use curve as guide for the motion